# Related model not updating in save override of a model being saved with ModelFormset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have Transaction model that is FK-d to a Share. In an 'Account' view, I have a ModelFormset of these Transactions and I can save multiple transactions by looping through the forms and saving them.

On my Transaction's save() method I try and update the balance on the linked Share. this works if I save one transaction, but when I POST my ModelFormset with multiple transactions, everytime I hit the *self.share.balance = self.share.balance + amt* line in the Transaction save() override (that is for every new Transaction), the share.balance is what it was before any of the previous transactions in the formset were saved.

Does anyone know why the added amount to share balance from a previous saved transaction is not carried on the subsequent saves (why only the last Transaction's amount will be added to share balance)?

***Transaction* model which should update balance on parent-model *Share***

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    share = models.ForeignKey(Share, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    db_cr = models.CharField(choices=DBCR, max_length=2)
    amt = models.DecimalField('Amount', max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    post_dt = models.DateTimeField('Post Time', null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

        ...

            if self.share:
                if self in self.share.transaction_set.all():
                    logging.error('Transaction %s already posted' % self.id)
                    return False

                amt = self.amt if self.db_cr == 'cr' else -self.amt
                self.share.balance = self.share.balance + amt
                self.share.save()
```

**Share Model**

```
class Share(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.ForeignKey(ShareDef, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    balance = models.DecimalField('Balance', max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s'%(self.account,
                   self.name,
                   self.definition.sym_code,
                   self.balance )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if not self.name:
                self.name = self.definition.name
        super(Share, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In view, I have a Transaction formset

```
#...in view
TranFormSet = modelformset_factory(Transaction, exclude=('origin','ach_entry'), extra=1)

if request.method=='POST':
...
    tran_formset = TranFormSet(request.POST)
...
    if tran_formset.is_valid():
        for form in tran_formset:

            tran = form.save(commit=False)
            tran.account = account
            tran.origin = 'tt'
            tran.save()

else:

    #...following kind of weird because of how I'm setting querysets of ModelChoiceFields
    kwargs = {'account_instance': account}
    tran_formset = TranFormSet(queryset=Transaction.objects.none())
    tran_formset.form = (curry(TranForm, **kwargs))
```

**Form**

```
class TranForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        account_instance = kwargs.pop('account_instance', None)
        super(TranForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            if account_instance:
                self.fields['share'].queryset = account_instance.share_set.all()

            if self.instance.pk:
                del self.fields['share']



    class Meta:
        model=Transaction
        exclude=['origin', 'ach_entry', 'account']


    post_dt = forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.date.today(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
{
    'class': 'datepicker'
}))

    share = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label='---------', required=False, queryset=Share.objects.all())
```

Comment: Is it possible the saves for transactions are running in parallel? They look sequential looking at your code, but your problem sounds like a race condition

Comment: I wouldn’t know how to check - I put a break point in and ran in debug, and even going slowly this problem occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what may be causing the issue, but it may be helpful to perform the update of the `self.share.balance` in a single `update()` query. This can be done using [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```py
from django.db.models import F

class Transaction(models.Model):
    # ...

    def update_share_balance(self):
        if self.db_cr == "cr":
            amount = self.amt
        else:
            amount = -self.amt

        # By using the queryset update() method, we can perform the
        # change in a single query, without using a potentially old
        # value from `self.share.balance`
        return Share.objects.filter(id=self.share_id).update(
            balance=F("balance") + amount
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # ...
            if self.share:
                # ...
                self.update_share_balance()

        # Also, be sure to call the super().save() method at the end!
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```